# Ansible npm install list in a single session

Tags: npm, ansible

I have a long list of items for Ansible npm install, and using a "with_items" is very slow. I would like to use a list in a single session, such as:

```
- name: "define list for npm install"
  set_fact:
    npm_install_list:
      - 'mkdirp'
      - 'request'
      - 'extend'
      ... lots more ...

- name: "npm install a list at once"
  npm:
    name: "{{ npm_install_list | join(' ') }}"
    registry: 'http://path.to.private.registry'
    global: yes
    state: present
```

I get this error:

```
no JSON object could be decoded
```

Could this work with npm? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could this work with npm?

No.

Just try with `name: package1 package2` and you will see why:

```
cmd: /bin/npm install --global 'package1 package2'
```

`name` argument expects a string and treats the given value as string thus escaping/quoting it.

—-

As a side note, some other package management modules in Ansible automatically combine the items (packages) into a single execution call (though primarily to avoid problems with dependencies, not for optimization). `npm` module does not.

Answer (score -1):

under **group_vats/all** define your array as top level

```
npm_install_list:
  - 'mkdirp'
  - 'request'
  - 'extend'
  ... lots more ...
```

Now use this array as usual in your role

```
- name: "npm install a list at once"
  npm:
    name: "{{ npm_install_list | join(' ') }}"
    registry: 'http://path.to.private.registry'
    global: yes
    state: present
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still get the same error. Maybe npm name can only take a single argument?

Comment: Hmm. You maybe right. I don't see any multiple installation example in the ansible npm documentation